# Measure total # of clients connected to one particular AP Android

Tags: android

I would like to know the total number of clients (devices) connected to one particular Wifi Access Point

Comment: Every model of AP I have ever ised has thay feature built into the admin panel. You wanna get quicl results check there, if you dont have admin access id suggest the airodump toolset, kismet, and wireshark in that order.

Comment: You want to determine this information from an android app, for any access point?